# PostgreSQL too many connections for role "user"

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am making a Chatbot that generates new questions and asks to people based on previous answers, the new questions have variables that I take from queries made to my PostgreSQL database.
However as I am creating a new session for every question and because my role in postgresql has a certain limit, after this limit is reached I receive the following error:

```
Error acquiring client error: too many connections for role "user"
```

Here you have an example of code that I am using to make queries, It is the same as I used for the rest of the questions:

```
let pool = new pg.Pool(config.PG_CONFIG);
                    pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
                        if (err) {
                            return console.error('Error acquiring client', err.stack);
                        }

                        console.log(`SELECT documentname FROM documentos`);

                        client.query(`SELECT documentname FROM documentos`,

                        function (err, result) {

                            if (err) {
                                console.log('Query error: ' + err);
                            }

                            else {

                                console.log("Cantidad de rows: "+result.rows.length);

                                let mensaje="Por favor selecciona tu tipo de documento";

                                for (let i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                                    console.log("Iterador i: "+i);

                                    let documentostipes = result.rows[i].documentname;

                                    console.log("Tipo de documentos: "+documentostipes+".");


                                    let quickcard2 ={
                                        "content_type": "text",
                                        "title": documentostipes,
                                        "payload": documentostipes,
                                        };

                                    quickcard.push(quickcard2);

                                }

                                let botonregresar ={
                                    "content_type": "text",
                                    "title": "Regresar",
                                    "payload": "Regresar",
                                };

                                quickcard.push(botonregresar);

                                console.log(quickcard);
                                sendQuickReply(sender,mensaje,quickcard);
                            }
                        });
                        //client.release();
                    });
                    pool.end();
```

I hope you could help me to understand what is wrong.

Thank you,

Jonathan Prieto

Comment: How many times is the code being my called? Also, reducing to a _minimal_ failing case, including calling context, will be beneficial to this question’s reception.

Comment: @user2864740 For each user I use arround 10 times similar codes to this one, so 10 sessions are created for each user.

Comment: any reason for not keeping pool alive and not using commenting out client.release()?

Comment: @Avi Sangray When I keep client.release, I receive an error telling that the connexion has been interrupted. Do you suggest me to keep the pool alive? Does that mean that I declare it only one time in the code? Or it just means that I remove the pool.end

Comment: Exactly just keep the pool alive. And instead of pool.connect() try using pool.query() directly

Comment: let me know if that worked

Comment: If you're having problems with that, you may wish to post a more complete example. It isn't clear how this fits into Dialogflow

Comment: @Avi Sangray it worked much butter, now it only creates one session for each question, but when I finish the chat, those sessions are eliminated and doesn´t stay open. So the last question could be, how to prevent one session per question, just to have one session per user or maybe one session per question but being able to close it after the question and not the end of the chat. (I removed pool.end and replaces pool.connect with pool.query directly)

Comment: @JonathanPrieto i don't think you should do that. are question being asked sequentially one by one or simultaneously(one single form)??

Comment: @Avi Sangray They are asked sequentially and depending on the answers, some could be asked and others not.

Comment: @JonathanPrieto it's not wise to open a session per user as your workload ain't intensive moreover this method manages pool itself so that's a better way